# How to wait for a response from a modal before continuing with ajax action link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have an actionlink which an `OnBegin` method which calls a modal asking to either "Save", "Don't Save" or "Cancel". I need to be able to wait for the users selection before continuing.

For example: if the user selects cancel then the modal closes and I return false to stop the ajax action link from continuing.

I know there is AjaxOption of Confirm which does something similar but there are a few issues with that:

1. The styling doesn't match the rest of my site.
2. It only has the options of canceling or continuing without an option for saving

ActionLink:

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "BrandCategoryModal", "BrandCategory", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DisplayModal", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET", OnBegin = "CheckForChanges()"})
```

javascript:

```
var hasChanged = false;
var catId = 0;
var form = document.getElementById("CheckForChanges");

form.addEventListener("input", function () {
    hasChanged = true;
    console.log("Change");
});

$('input[name=Active]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        hasChanged = true;
        console.log("Change");
    } else {
        hasChanged = true;
        console.log("Change");
    }
});
    function CheckForChanges() {
        if (hasChanged)
        {
            showModal('#SaveOrCancel');
      }
        showModal('#DisplayModal')
    }
    function showModal(modalId) { //Displays Modal
        $(modalId).modal('show');
    }
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="SaveOrCancel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 20%; margin-top: 5%">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Before Continuing:</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Select Your option:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" style="margin:auto"><b>Save</b></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" style="margin:auto"><b>Don't Save</b></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin:auto"><b>Cancel</b></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share the relevant code

Comment: You should probably look into [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) for this.  This is an out-of-the-box solution for dialog boxes, which use Bootstrap modals and they can be used with ajax.

Comment: Instead of an `Ajax.ActionLink` you could use an `Html.ActionLink` and handle the click event in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax call for a XMLHttpRequest, lets you handle the events when success, also let you decide when to continue waiting:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // Success ! <--- THERE IT IS
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  } else {
    // Reached server, but it returned an error. Your call. You can retry
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```